# portuguese tokenizer: t is breaking “ao” in “a” and “o”

Tags: tokenize

I am using the Spacy as a tokenizer for Portuguese documents (the last version).
But, it is making a mistake in the following sentence: 'esta quebrando aonde nao devia, separando a e o em ao e aos'.
It is breaking “ao” in “a” and “o”. The same is happening with other words like “aonde” (“a” + “onde”) and othes (“aos”, etc).
Other strange cases: "àquele" into "a" and "quele"; "às" into "à" and "s".
The problem can be shown in the "Test the model live (experimental)" in https://spacy.io/models/pt. 
For now, I am adding some known words with tokenizer.add_special_case. But I may not remember all cases.
Is it possible to adjust this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems appropriate to me break down the expression "ao" in two functional parts: preposition and article. Depending on the application, it would be simple to concatenate these parts together as required by the official grammar.

Comment: Other strange cases: "àquele" into "a" and "quele"; "às" into "à" and "s"; "às" is breaking into "à" and "s"